# NFS exports all_squash,anonuid,anongid mapping all client users to owner on server (working) still needs world readable permissions on the server?

Tags: permissions, nfs, chmod, chown

My /etc/exports on the NFS server:

```
/home/username/Documents/some/folders/deep   192.168.1.10(rw,sync,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
```

This seems to be working as intended for the most part.  Any actions done by **any/all users** on the client OS are being written using uid:1000 on the server.

Yet the NFS share cannot be accessed/mounted at all by the client unless the server has permissions "755" on the /home/username folder.  Considering that all access/actions coming from the NFS client are being successfully mapped to the server's uid:1000 account, shouldn't "700" permissions suffice on the /home/username folder on the server?  All files and folders are owned by "username" on the server, aside from /home itself.

It seems that the /home/username folder needs world read+execute permissions for the client to access it, even though all their requests are already being mapped to the owner user ("username" / uid:1000) on the server.

Have I misunderstood something here?  Seeing the mapping appears to work mostly, why does /home/username need to be world readable?

Comment: Dang! A masterfully asked question, but no answer in seven years... and I'm still searching for an answer as well :-P